# MySQL Tell if No Train Trips Route Back to Start From Arrived Station

Tags: mysql, sql

Find stations that are the start of a route to another station, but not the destination of Any route from the other station.

Trying to print name of train stations in Japan that are a start of a route to another station with no duplicates and ordered alphabetically, but not the destination of any route from that other train station. So, if route 1->2 exists and 3->1 does not exist, whatever round-trip exists on 1 (such as 1->2 and 2->1), 1 is still considered as part of results.

Database set up as:

```
TABLE = Stations
id|name_station |country|manager_name|time_zone  |number_of_employees
1 | Tokyo Grand | Japan | Satoshi    | Japan Time| 500
2 | Nagasaki    |Japan  | Hirohito   | Japan Time| 345
3 | Tokyo suburb|Japan  | Kiki.      | Japan Time| 344



  TABLE = train_routes
start_station_id| end_station_id | date_of_last_trip
      1         |      3         | 07.20.2020
      1         |      2         | 07.21.2020
      2         |      1         | 07.21.2020
```

Based off this table we include Tokyo Grand in final results due to it has a route to Tokyo Suburb, but no trip from Tokyo Suburb back to Tokyo grand as a route. The round trip between Tokyo Grand and Nagasaki does not stop Tokyo grand from being listed as a starting point, with no trips back to it.

So end result is returning just the unique station names of stations that follow this condition and organize alphabetically. Based off this data it seems the stations.id, train_routes.start_station_id, routes.end_station_id, and stations.country are the only relevant items for this problem. The manager name, time zone, number of employees, and date of last trip do not matter.

So the process seems to see if no return trip exists back from the traveled to station based off ids filtered off Japan country stations. Add the starting station if it has no return trip from the traveled to station. Then add have the ids replaced with the name of the stations.

Comment: I'm finding this requirement difficult to understand. To make it clearer, I'd suggest the following. 1) Provide us with a sample train_routes table, containing perhaps 10 rows of data. 2) Tell us the station ID of a station that should appear in the results, and explain why it should appear. 3) Tell us the station ID of a station that should NOT appear in the results, and explain why it should not appear.

Comment: Updated the table giving an example and explanation

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, I think:

```
select distinct
    s1.name_station
from
    train_routes r1
inner join
    Stations s1
on
    r1.start_station_id = s1.id
left outer join
    train_routes r2
on
    r1.start_station_id = r2.end_station_id
    and r1.end_station_id = r2.start_station_id
where
    r2.end_station_id is null
    and s1.country = 'Japan'
order by
    s1.name_station
```